# Is $\lim_{n\to \infty} L {\varphi_n} = L \lim_{n\to \infty} {\varphi_n}$ for $L=I-A$ where $A$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $A:X\to X$ be a compact linear operator on a normed space $X$. Define $L = I - A$. Also suppose that $I-A$ is bijective (although I'm not sure if this is relevant to the question I am going to ask).

Can we say that for some convergent sequence $\{\varphi_n\}$ in $X$ that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} L {\varphi_n} = L \lim_{n\to \infty} {\varphi_n}
$$
If so, why?

Comment: ??? This is clear just because $L$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the desired conclusion
$$
\text{for every convergent sequence $\varphi_n$ in $X$,}\quad
\lim_{n\to \infty} L {\varphi_n} = L \lim_{n\to \infty} {\varphi_n}
$$
a mathematician would say: "$L$ is continuous."  If your definition of "compact linear operator" includes continuous, then (since $I$ is continuous and the sum of continuous operators is continuous) we may answer YES to the question.

Comment: Ok, so compact implies bounded which implies continuous and then we have $I-A$ when is the difference of continuous operators which is again continuous. Therefore we can switch the position of the limits.